# I have tags separated by comma and I want to filter those tags using MUI Select

Tags: reactjs, filter, material-ui, tags, filtering

```
[
  {id: 'AjRzfMxbfJMphK144DIAr', title: 'javascript', tags: 'code,programining', notes: "This book is a must to", createdAt: 1671459053853}
  {id: 'kvdo7HrLr2GeOUX9j4qLq', title: 'css', tags: 'css,code', notes: " mo…his book is a must to have", createdAt: 1671459781356}
  {id: 'qQLcIV0sm_AQmdiJgrTpN', title: 'reactjs', tags: 'html,reactjs', notes: "JavaScript's most frequently…nterview ", createdAt: 1671464489642}
  {id: 'x1wqP1PV73R35JvGX7lwh', title: 'nodejs', tags: 'html,css', notes: "Colleuently…nave", createdAt: 1671468792674}
  length
]
```

I have tags I want to filter that tags using material ui select chip - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#chip

I try using includes method but its only take 1 string can anyone help me?

Filtering in reactjs using `multiSelect` option

Comment: Check below answer and let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you.

```
{array.map((name) => {
   return name.tags.split(',').map((tag) => {
      return (
         <MenuItem key={tag} value={tag}>{tag}</MenuItem>
      )
   })
})}
```

[image: Here is the result]

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your data with array of object

const data = [
  {
    id: 'AjRzfMxbfJMphK144DIAr',
    title: 'javascript',
    tags: 'code,programining',
    notes: 'This book is a must to',
    createdAt: 1671459053853,
  },
  {
    id: 'kvdo7HrLr2GeOUX9j4qLq',
    title: 'css',
    tags: 'css,code',
    notes: ' mo…his book is a must to have',
    createdAt: 1671459781356,
  },
  {
    id: 'qQLcIV0sm_AQmdiJgrTpN',
    title: 'reactjs',
    tags: 'html,reactjs',
    notes: "JavaScript's most frequently…nterview ",
    createdAt: 1671464489642,
  },
  {
    id: 'x1wqP1PV73R35JvGX7lwh',
    title: 'nodejs',
    tags: 'html,css',
    notes: 'Colleuently…nave',
    createdAt: 1671468792674,
  },
];


// Now make a array using map for your select options

const tags = [];
data.map((item) => {
  tags.push(...item.tags.split(','));
});


//Now use this array in your mui select options

<Select>
  {tags.map((item) => (
    <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
      {item}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation about the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).